# Best way to rebind data in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3.js library to generate contents based on data.

Here is a simplified example.

```
data_arr = [0,1,2,3,4];
d3.select("#mylist").selectAll('li').data(data_arr).enter().append("li").html(
    function(d)
    {
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        element.innerHTML = '<div id="innerDiv">' + d + '</div>';
        return element.innerHTML;
   });
```

If I change my array, for example the new data is [5,3]. How is the best way to rebind and show the new html? Do I have to call the same sentence again or is it a better way?

Consider the case of a more complex data structure.
i.e.

```
data_arr = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4];
```

and

```
element.innerHTML = '<div id="innerDiv">' + d.field + '</div>';
```

What happens if I do obj1.field = 'newValue'. How is the rebind done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a function. For example, here's a function that will populate a list from an array of strings:

```
function list(ul, data) {
  var li = ul.selectAll("li").data(data);
  li.exit().remove();
  li.enter().append("li");
  li.text(function(d) { return d; });
}
```

Now if you want to initialize your list, you can say:

```
d3.select("#list").call(list, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Then later if you want to update, you can say:

```
d3.select("#list").call(list, [5, 3]);
```

If you prefer (and you don't need method chaining), you can write this without [selection.call](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-call):

```
list(d3.select("#list"), [5, 3]);
```

Comment: my scenario is a little more complicated. My data are complex objects. If I have data_arr = [obj1, obj2, obj3]; and I change obj1.field = newvalue;  What happens If I want to rebind? Do I have to make d3.select("#mylist").selectAll('li').remove();  and call "list" function again? Is there a better way?

Comment: No, you don't need to remove all the li elements; the data-join removes only the exiting elements. if you update your data without adding or removing any objects, then you can just `d3.select("#list").call(list, data)` to update the display. In this case the enter and exit selection are empty.

Comment: But doing that does not update the #innerDiv content if a specific field of the object has changed. Or Am I doing something wrong? Should d3.select("#list").call(list, data) update the content of #innerDiv with the new value of d.field?

Comment: The line `li.text(function(d) { return d; })` affects both entering and updating elements, so yes, it will update with the new value. Your original code only updated the entering elements.